# Figuring out why a specific bit of CSS is not being applied as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a secondary theme for a site of mine (a dark theme). & I can not understand why a specific bit of CSS is not being applied to a particular element, even though it is being applied on another element that is identical.

URL to the site: https://phpstack-726541-2423367.cloudwaysapps.com/  Toggle the switch in the top right hand corner to enable the dark theme.  You can see that it only applies it to the 'Header'  & not the 'Footer' even though it can be seen that they both use the same classes through Inspect element.

```js
  document.querySelector('.switch').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('light');

  document.querySelector('.navbar').classList.toggle('light');
  document.querySelector('button').classList.toggle('light');
  document.querySelector('#menu-btn').classList.toggle('light');
  document.querySelector('.wve-editor-player').classList.toggle('light');
  });
```

```css
/* video editor */
body { padding: 90px 0; background-color: #101010;}
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    body { padding: 0; }
    body > .container { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    body > .container > .card { border: 0; border-radius: 0; background-color: transparent !important;}
}
.navbar { background-color: #191919; height: 89px; border-bottom: solid 1px #414040; box-shadow: 1px 1px #414040;}
.big { font-size: 120%; }
.small { font-size: 80%; }
.code { max-height: 500px; padding: 5px; overflow: auto; background-color: #eee; }
.btn[disabled] { cursor: not-allowed; color: #fff; background-color: #6c757d; border-color: #6c757d; }
.shadow-1 { box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }

video,
audio { width: 100%; box-sizing: content-box; }

/* logo */
.logo { color: #0099FF; font-size: 20px; }
.logo img { width: auto; max-width: 200px; margin: -69px; margin-top: -6.9%; padding-left: 50px;}
.logo a { text-decoration: none; }

/* colors */
.bg-white { background-color: #fff; }
.color-blue { color: #236bf1; }
.color-red { color: #f13d2a; }

/* common */
.no-margin { margin: 0 !important; }
.no-wrap { white-space: nowrap; }
.show-on-hover-parent { position: relative; }
.show-on-hover { position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; display: none; }
.show-on-hover-parent:hover .show-on-hover { display: block; }
.card-default { background-color: #F5F5F5; }
.display-inline-block { display: inline-block; }
.btn { cursor: pointer; border-radius: 6EM; border: solid 1px #0099FF;}
.btn:hover { background-color: #CCC; color: #000;}
#import-bttn {background-color: #0099FF; color: #FFF !important;}
.text-ellipsis { display: block; text-align: left; max-width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
.max-height300 { max-height: 300px; overflow: auto; }
.relative { position: relative; }
.position-absolute { position: absolute; }
.pos-absolute-left { left: 15px; top: 15px; }
.pos-absolute-right { right: 15px; top: 15px; }
.pos-absolute-bottom-left { left: 15px; bottom: 15px; }

/* login */
.card-login { margin-top: 150px; }
.card-login form { margin-bottom: 0; }

/* margins */
.margin-top { margin-top: 1rem; }
.margin-bottom { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
.margin-vert { margin-top: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem; }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .margin-bottom-md { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
}

/* button */
/* .btn {background-color: #161616;} */
.btn:not(.btn-link) { transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease; }
.btn:not(.btn-link):hover { box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }
.btn[class*="-outline"] { transition: background-color 0.3s ease; background-color: #0099FF; border: solid 1px #101010; color: #FFF !important;}
.btn-icon [class^="icon-"] { line-height: 1.4rem; }
.btn-smp { padding: 0.6rem 1.5rem; }
.btn-outline-info { border-color:#CCC; color: #9E9E9E !important;}
.control-buttons {padding: 0 13px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 36px; margin: 0px 6px; float: right;}
#editor-controls {margin-top: 40px;}

/* form fields */
.form-control[type="text"],
.form-control[type="email"],
.form-control[type="number"],
.form-control[type="password"],
textarea.form-control { background-color: #f1f1f1; box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
textarea.form-control:focus { background-color: #f1f1f1; }
input[type="range"] { width: 100%; padding: 0; }
.input-range { padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 4px; }

/* dropdown-menu */
.dropdown-menu { box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }

/* editor-player */
.wve-editor-player { position: relative; background-color: #161515; border:solid 1px #404040; border-radius: 6px;}
.wve-editor-player video { width: 100%; height: 360px; border-radius: 6px;}
.wve-editor-player-panel { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; padding: 5px 20px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); opacity: 1; transition: opacity 300ms; }
.wve-editor-player .time { float: right; }
.wve-editor-player .time-current { float: left; }
.wve-editor-player:hover .wve-editor-player-panel { opacity: 0; }

/* list-group */
.list-group {  }
.list-group .list-group-item.active .btn-link { color: #fff; }
.list-group .list-group-item .btn-link { max-width: 100%; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; border: none;}
.list-group-item a,
.list-group-item .btn-link { text-decoration: none; }
span.btn.btn-link:hover { background: none; }

/* editor-timeline */
.editor-timeline-wrapper { position: relative; }
#wve-timeline { position: relative; width: 100%; height: 20px; z-index: 11; overflow: hidden; background: none transparent; border: 0; }
#wve-timeline .ui-slider-handle { z-index: 12; width: 12px; height: 20px; top: 0; margin-left: -6px; margin-top: 0; background: none transparent; border: 0; outline: none; }
#wve-timeline .ui-slider-handle:before { content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; margin-left: -5px; width: 0; height: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 6px 5px 0 5px; border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent; }
#wve-timeline .ui-slider-handle:after { content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 50%; margin-left: -5px; width: 0; height: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0 5px 6px 5px; border-color: transparent transparent #000000 transparent; }

#wve-timeline-range { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 20px; z-index: 12; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); background: none #eee; border-radius: 0; box-shadow: none !important; }
#wve-timeline-range .noUi-connect { background: none #aaa; }
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-origin { z-index: 10 !important; }
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-connects:first-child + .noUi-origin { z-index: 5 !important; }
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower { height: 20px; border: 0; top: -1px !important; background: none transparent; box-shadow: none; }
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower:before { content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; margin-left: -5px; width: 0; height: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 6px 5px 0 5px; border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent; background-color: transparent; }
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower:after { content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; bottom: 0; top: auto; left: 50%; margin-left: -5px; width: 0; height: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0 5px 6px 5px; border-color: transparent transparent #000000 transparent; background-color: transparent; }

/* btn-group-justified */
.btn-group-justified { display: flex; width: 100%; }
.btn-group-justified .btn,
.btn-group-justified .btn-group { flex: 1; }
.btn-group-justified .btn { width: 100%; }

/* progress bar */
.progress { border: none; }
#wve-user-stat {display: none;}

/* preloader */
.wve-preloader { position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1111; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
.wve-preloader-inner { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -70px 0 0 -150px; width: 300px; max-width: 100%; z-index: 1112; padding: 15px; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 6px; }
.wve-preloader-caption { padding: 0 0 15px 0; text-align: center; }
.wve-preloader-content { height: 20px; background: url("../img/preloader.gif") center center no-repeat; }
.wve-preloader-progress {  }
.wve-preloader-progress .progress { border: 1px solid #b1b1b1; }
.wve-preloader-progress .progress-bar { width: 0; height: auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 0 0 0; }
.wve-preloader-progress .progress-bar-empty { padding-top: 20px; }

/* bottom-list-container */
.bottom-list-container { max-height: 338px; overflow: auto; }
.bottom-list-container td { min-width: 150px; }

/* episode-item */
.wve-episode-container { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.episode-item { float: left; margin-top: 15px; padding: 15px 5px; }
.episode-item > .card { border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7); background: url("../img/preloader_circle.gif") no-repeat center center transparent; opacity: 1; overflow: hidden; }
.episode-item .card-block { min-height: 80px; background: none no-repeat center center transparent; background-size: cover; }
.episode-item > .card:hover { background-image: none; }
.episode-item > .card:hover .card-block { opacity: 0.3; }
#wve-episode-container {padding: 0px 55px 0px 55px;}

/* video-thumbnail */
.video-thumbnail { min-height: 150px; background: #eee url("../img/icon_film.png") center center no-repeat; }

/* wve-time-selected-inputs */
#wve-time-selected-inputs { width: 340px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: -56px; display: none; }
#wve-time-selected-inputs .card-block { background-color: #b6b6b6; }
#wve-time-selected-inputs .card-block input.form-control { background-color: #a5a5a5; color: #fff; }
#wve-time-selected-inputs .card-block input.form-control:focus,
#wve-time-selected-inputs .card-block input.form-control:active { border-color: #6f6f6f; }

.card { border: none; background-color: transparent;}

.form-group { margin-top: 16px; margin-bottom: 1rem; }

#footer { background-color: #FFF; border-top: solid 1px #CCC; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px#ececec; display: none; }

#footer-padding { padding: 10px 9px 9px 40px; }

::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 6px; }
  
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: #0099FF; width: 6px; border-radius: 6px; }


/* light theme css */
body.light { background-color: #F9F9F9; }
div.navbar.light { background-color: #FFF; border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC; box-shadow: 1px 1px #ececec}
button.btn.light { background-color: #FFF; background-color: #FFF; color: #909090 !important; border: solid 1px #CCC;}
div.wve-editor-player.light { background-color: #DDD; border: 1px solid #DDD;}
```

```html
<div class="navbar nav-expand fixed-top light" id = "header">
    <div class="col-md-2 order-md-10 text-right">
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch" style = "display: inline-block; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input switch" id="customSwitch1">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"></label>
           </div>
        <div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-info light" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="icon-menu"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="action" data-action="profile">
                    <span class="icon-user-tie"></span>
                    <?php echo $lang['profile']; ?>
                </a>
                <?php if( $user['role'] == 'admin' ): ?>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $config['base_url'] . $config['home_url']; ?>?action=users">
                        <span class="icon-users"></span>
                        <?php echo $lang['users']; ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $userOptions['show_log'] ): ?>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="action" data-action="log">
                        <span class="icon-file-text"></span>
                        <?php echo $lang['log']; ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $config['authentication'] ): ?>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $config['base_url'] . $config['home_url']; ?>index.php?action=logout">
                        <span class="icon-exit"></span>
                        <?php echo $lang['log_out']; ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2 text-sm-left text-center">
        <h2 class="logo">
            <img src="<?php echo $config['logo_image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $config['app_title']; ?>">
            <!--<span class="d-inline-block ml-2"><?php echo $config['app_title']; ?></span>-->
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2">
        <div id="wve-user-stat">
            <div class="progress mt-3">
                <div class="progress-bar <?php if($userOptions['files_size_percent'] >= 85): ?>bg-danger<?php else: ?>bg-success<?php endif; ?>" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo $userOptions['files_size_percent']; ?>%" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $userOptions['files_size_percent']; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center small mb-3">
                <?php echo $lang['used']; ?>:
                <?php echo $userOptions['files_size_percent']; ?>%
                &mdash;
                <?php echo $userOptions['files_size_total']; ?>
                /
                <?php echo $userOptions['files_size_max']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-smp btn-outline-primary btn-block" data-toggle="action" data-action="import" id = "import-bttn">
                <span class="icon-download"></span>
                <?php echo $lang['import_media']; ?>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3" style="max-height: 338px; overflow: auto;">
            <ul class="list-group" id="wve-list_input">
              
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">

                <div class="wve-editor-player light">
                    <video src="" preload="auto" width="400" height="360" class="d-block" id="wve-video"></video>
                    <div class="wve-editor-player-panel" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="time" id="wve-editor-player-time"></div>
                        <div class="time time-current" id="wve-editor-player-time-current"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vid_btns" id = "editor-controls">
                <button type="button" class="btn light" data-toggle="action" data-action="stepback_main">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><path d="M11 16.07V7.93c0-.81-.91-1.28-1.58-.82l-5.77 4.07c-.56.4-.56 1.24 0 1.63l5.77 4.07c.67.47 1.58 0 1.58-.81zm1.66-3.25l5.77 4.07c.66.47 1.58-.01 1.58-.82V7.93c0-.81-.91-1.28-1.58-.82l-5.77 4.07c-.57.4-.57 1.24 0 1.64z"></path></svg> <span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Step back</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn light" data-toggle="action" data-action="play_main">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" fill="currentColor"><g><rect fill="none" height="24" width="24"></rect></g><g><path d="M12,2C6.48,2,2,6.48,2,12s4.48,10,10,10s10-4.48,10-10S17.52,2,12,2z M9.5,14.67V9.33c0-0.79,0.88-1.27,1.54-0.84 l4.15,2.67c0.61,0.39,0.61,1.29,0,1.68l-4.15,2.67C10.38,15.94,9.5,15.46,9.5,14.67z"></path></g></svg> <span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Play</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn light" data-toggle="action" data-action="stepforward_main">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M5.58 16.89l5.77-4.07c.56-.4.56-1.24 0-1.63L5.58 7.11C4.91 6.65 4 7.12 4 7.93v8.14c0 .81.91 1.28 1.58.82zM13 7.93v8.14c0 .81.91 1.28 1.58.82l5.77-4.07c.56-.4.56-1.24 0-1.63l-5.77-4.07c-.67-.47-1.58 0-1.58.81z"></path></svg> <span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Step forward</span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn light" data-toggle="action" data-action="take-episode">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M3 6c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v13c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h13c.55 0 1-.45 1-1s-.45-1-1-1H5c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V7c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zm17-4H8c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-2 9h-3v3c0 .55-.45 1-1 1s-1-.45-1-1v-3h-3c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1 1-1h3V6c0-.55.45-1 1-1s1 .45 1 1v3h3c.55 0 1 .45 1 1s-.45 1-1 1z"></path></svg> <span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Take episode</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn light" data-toggle="action" data-action="play_selected">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M10.8 15.9l4.67-3.5c.27-.2.27-.6 0-.8L10.8 8.1c-.33-.25-.8-.01-.8.4v7c0 .41.47.65.8.4zM12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"></path></svg> <span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Play episode</span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn light" data-toggle="action" data-action="cut-fast">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M9.64 7.64c.29-.62.42-1.33.34-2.09-.19-1.73-1.54-3.2-3.26-3.49-2.77-.48-5.14 1.89-4.66 4.65.3 1.72 1.76 3.07 3.49 3.26.76.08 1.46-.05 2.09-.34L10 12l-2.36 2.36c-.62-.29-1.33-.42-2.09-.34-1.73.19-3.2 1.54-3.49 3.26-.48 2.77 1.89 5.13 4.65 4.65 1.72-.3 3.07-1.76 3.26-3.49.08-.76-.05-1.46-.34-2.09L12 14l7.59 7.59c.89.89 2.41.26 2.41-1v-.01c0-.37-.15-.73-.41-1L9.64 7.64zM6 8c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm0 12c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm6-7.5c-.28 0-.5-.22-.5-.5s.22-.5.5-.5.5.22.5.5-.22.5-.5.5zm7.59-10.09L13 9l2 2 6.59-6.59c.26-.26.41-.62.41-1V3.4c0-1.25-1.52-1.88-2.41-.99z"></path></svg> <span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Cut fast</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button light" class="btn light rev" data-toggle="action" data-action="render">
                    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21.98 15.65C21.16 14.64 19.91 14 18.5 14C17.44 14 16.46 14.37 15.69 14.99C14.65 15.81 14 17.08 14 18.5C14 19.34 14.24 20.14 14.65 20.82C14.92 21.27 15.26 21.66 15.66 21.98H15.67C16.44 22.62 17.43 23 18.5 23C19.64 23 20.67 22.58 21.46 21.88C21.81 21.58 22.11 21.22 22.35 20.82C22.76 20.14 23 19.34 23 18.5C23 17.42 22.62 16.42 21.98 15.65ZM20.76 17.94L18.36 20.16C18.22 20.29 18.03 20.36 17.85 20.36C17.66 20.36 17.47 20.29 17.32 20.14L16.21 19.03C15.92 18.74 15.92 18.26 16.21 17.97C16.5 17.68 16.98 17.68 17.27 17.97L17.87 18.57L19.74 16.84C20.04 16.56 20.52 16.58 20.8 16.88C21.09 17.19 21.07 17.66 20.76 17.94Z"></path><path d="M14.7295 5.86V2.5C14.7295 2.22 14.5095 2 14.2295 2H9.76953C9.48953 2 9.26953 2.22 9.26953 2.5V5.86C9.26953 6.14 9.48953 6.36 9.76953 6.36H14.2295C14.5095 6.36 14.7295 6.14 14.7295 5.86Z"></path><path d="M7.24851 2.0207C4.68851 2.1807 2.93851 3.5007 2.28851 5.7007C2.18851 6.0307 2.42851 6.3607 2.76851 6.3607H7.26851C7.54851 6.3607 7.76851 6.1407 7.76851 5.8607V2.5207C7.76851 2.2407 7.52851 2.0007 7.24851 2.0207Z"></path><path d="M16.7505 2.00898C19.3105 2.16898 21.0605 3.48898 21.7105 5.68898C21.8105 6.01898 21.5705 6.34898 21.2305 6.34898H16.7305C16.4505 6.34898 16.2305 6.12898 16.2305 5.84898V2.50898C16.2305 2.22898 16.4705 1.98898 16.7505 2.00898Z"></path><path d="M22 8.35937V12.7394C22 13.1094 21.61 13.3494 21.28 13.1794C20.44 12.7394 19.48 12.4994 18.5 12.4994C16.89 12.4994 15.32 13.1594 14.2 14.3094C13.1 15.4294 12.5 16.9194 12.5 18.4994C12.5 19.3094 12.82 20.3494 13.22 21.2194C13.38 21.5694 13.14 21.9994 12.75 21.9994H7.81C4.6 21.9994 2 19.3994 2 16.1894V8.35937C2 8.07937 2.22 7.85938 2.5 7.85938H21.5C21.78 7.85938 22 8.07937 22 8.35937Z"></path></svg> Create Video
                </button>
            </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

            </div>

        </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<!-- Timeline slider -->
<div class="navbar nav-expand fixed-bottom light">
    <div class="card-body">

        <div class="editor-timeline-wrapper">
            <div id="wve-timeline"></div>
            <div id="wve-timeline-range"></div>
            <div id="wve-time-selected-inputs">
                <div class="card card-body py-2 px-4 shadow-1 bg-secondary">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-5 pl-1 pr-1">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm wve-time-input-in" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-5 pl-1 pr-1">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm wve-time-input-out" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 pl-1 pr-1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-block text-center p-1">
                                <i class="icon-cross"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Timeline slider -->

<!--episode/clip(s) container-->
<div class="episode-container" id="wve-episode-container" style="display: none;">
            <hr class="mb-0">
            <div class="row wve-episode-container" id="wve-episode-container-inner"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<!-- Output list -->
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">

        <div class="bottom-list-container border rounded-0">

            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="40%">
                    <col width="20%">
                    <col width="15%">
                    <col width="15%">
                    <col width="10%">
                </colgroup>
                <tbody id="wve-list_output"></tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Output list -->

<script>

  document.querySelector('.switch').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('light');

  document.querySelector('.navbar').classList.toggle('light');
  document.querySelector('button').classList.toggle('light');
  document.querySelector('#menu-btn').classList.toggle('light');
  document.querySelector('.wve-editor-player').classList.toggle('light');
  });

</script>
```

Image included of the desired result as well. Thanks for any input or proposal in advance!

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvWdk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that your problem stems from you using **querySelector()**

Since the output will always be the **first** element matching the criteria (in your case it seems to be your header)
( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector )

Try using an id instead for your footer or using **querySelectorAll()** which will return a list of elements
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Hope I could help you, keep me updated if you fixed it ! :)

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing this out! I have tried you're proposal to set a ID, but it seems to cause further troubles (as it just disappears completely).  I have removed the appended "light" class from the 'Footer' & it does appear to resemble the header. But it remains dark regardless if the dark theme is active or not.  You can see for you're self when removing the light class through Inspect

Comment: Weird, by adding an ID to the footer it disapear completly ?
If so you could always toggle every elements from the list given by querySelectorAll(), tho you'd have to loop them all (which can affect elements thats has the same class but shouldnt be touched) and the solution is janky at best

Perhaps try with another custom class design only for the ones you want to affect the theme

Comment: Yea strange for sure. Might you be willing to connect with me perhaps via live-share maybe?  It's a visual studio code ext for allowing collaboration, & working on code with others in real time.

Comment: Sadly I cant live chat, since I don't have much free-time. But I'll gladly take a deeper look at your code later or tomorrow when I'll find a bit of time. But feel free to message me tomorrow during the day if your problem is still unfixed :)

Comment: I would not be able to send you a direct message, as I don't believe direct messaging user's is possible here.  Perhaps maybe we could connect on Skype if you have one?  If so add me there & I can follow up later, permitting this issue would still be unresolved.   You can find me under the username Raiden :)  Just let me know it's you when adding me, or drop your Skype instead.

Comment: No problems, tho I cant find you in the sea of user called Raiden, you can find me with the username "Canadian_Pixel" it should be easier to find me

Answer (score 0):

As Canadian_Pixel [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71670036/2813224). In addition, `.querySelecyorAll()` returns a NodeList which is an array-like object consisting of all elements that the selector (a string identical to a CSS selector, ex. `".navbar"`) matches. In order to execute a class change on each `.navbar` within the NodeList you'll need to iterate though it as if it is an array. At this point you can work with a NodeList and use some basic Array methods and loops, or convert the NodeList into an array (*see end of this answer*). In this case, the former (ie. NodeList) is good enough.

Replace this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.navbar').classList.toggle('light');
```

with this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.navbar').forEach(nav => nav.classList.toggle('light'));
```

The above works 100%, I already tested it on your [site](https://phpstack-726541-2423367.cloudwaysapps.com/). If for some reason you need the whole arsenal of the Array API:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar'));
```

OR

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.navbar')]
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the feedback & taking the time to lend a helping hand on this.  It is immensely appreciated, & I can now sleep a bit better tonight as that's one less thing to resolve.  Thanks again for taking the time to offer a response on this!

Comment: @Username-reserved Um, ok, it should work, it'd be cool if you confirmed it.

Comment: Yes it does indeed work!  Thanks again for the proposal :)

Comment: You should accept Canadian_Pixel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71670036/2813224) by clicking the green ✅ at least.

Comment: Done!  I would also like to acknowledge that you're response was of value as well. So I have upvoted your answer, since I can only accept one answer.